# Appending a new key and values to each element in a array of Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi everyone I hope you are well, I have an array of objects list and and need to create a string made up of object key values and concatnenate them to form a new string, whihc will become the key property value of a new greeting key I need to add at the end of each object in my array. I can create the string and I can do the add greeting part, I am just struggling to find a way to add it to the end of each array rather than at the end of all the array or start. The result I am lookin for is below. Help much appreciated:0)

```
const a = [
  { 
    firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 'Americas', age: 35, 
    language: 'Java',
    greeting: 'Hi Sofia, what do you like the most about Java?'
  },
  { 
    firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 35, 
    language: 'Python',
    greeting: 'Hi Lukas, what do you like the most about Python?'
  },
  { 
    firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'U.', country: 'United States', continent: 'Americas', age: 32, 
    language: 'Ruby',
    greeting: 'Hi Madison, what do you like the most about Ruby?'
  } 
];
```

My code to date...

```
function greetDevelopers(list) {
  var firstName1 = list[0].firstName; 
  
  list.push(fullstring);

  var firstName2 = list[1].firstName;
  var fullstring2 = "Hi " +list[1].firstName + ", what do you like most about " +list[1].language 
  + "?"
  
  list.push = fullstring2;
  
  console.log(list);
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Basically the below objects in my list array with the greeting key added and the associated key value                                                                                         
           firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 'Americas', age: 35, 
    language: 'Java',
    greeting: 'Hi Sofia, what do you like the most about Java?'
  },

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to iterate over all the objects in the array, then append the key to each object with the following: `list[i]["greeting"] = "blahblah"`

Answer (score 0):

```js
   

var a = [
  { 
    firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 'Americas', age: 35, 
    language: 'Java'
  },
  { 
    firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 35, 
    language: 'Python'
  },
  { 
    firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'U.', country: 'United States', continent: 'Americas', age: 32, 
    language: 'Ruby'
  } 
];

function greetDevelopers(list) {
list.forEach((e,i) => {
a[i]['greeting'] =  "Hi " +e.firstName + ", what do you like most about " +e.language 
  + "?";
})
}
greetDevelopers(a);

  console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should to the trick:

```js
const a = [
  { 
    firstName: 'Sofia', lastName: 'I.', country: 'Argentina', continent: 'Americas', age: 35, 
    language: 'Java',
  },
  { 
    firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 35, 
    language: 'Python',
  },
  { 
    firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'U.', country: 'United States', continent: 'Americas', age: 32, 
    language: 'Ruby',
  } 
];

const result = a.map(person => {
  const greeting = `Hi ${person.firstName}, what do you like the most about ${person.language}?`;
  return {...person, greeting};
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Christian for your help can you see what I am doing wrong ? The copnsole log works but the return statement returns undefined                                                            function greetDevelopers(list) {

   const result = list.map(person => {
  const greeting = `Hi ${person.firstName}, what do you like the most about ${person.language}?`;
   
   return {person, greeting};
})
     console.log(result)
     }

Comment: You mean the function `greetDevelopers` returns `undefined`?